# ngFor based on type

Tags: angular

now it is printing two times no Data. I just want to replace third one with no data as type 3 is not exist in array.

So my condition is sometime i get array with type 3 or type 2 or type 1 
if array does not have type 3 or type 2 or type 1 then just print only one time.

Actually i am not getting the way to do :(

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r85hhs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

app.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of test">
 <ng-container *ngIf="item.type === 1">
   <p>  {{item.name}}</p>
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container *ngIf="item.type === 2">
   <p>  {{item.name}}</p>
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container *ngIf="item.type === 3">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
 </ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="item.type !== 3">
NO data
</ng-container> 
</ng-container>
```

app.component.ts

```
  public test = [{type:1, name:'shawn'},
   {type:2, name:"ronny"}
  ]
```

[image]
Thank you

Comment: To clarify, you want the output to be: `shawn ronny NO data`?

Comment: yes wroker suppose i get the new array that does not have type 2 then in that case i want to print this shawn no data indra

Comment: How many `types` are there? Can you please provide the desired output on your question.

Comment: there are only 3 types i got the all type from api 
 ````public test = [{type:1, name:'shawn'},
   {type:2, name:"ronny"},
   {type:3, name:"tranny"}
  ]

i dont get the type1
public test = [{type:2, name:'Test2'},
   {type:3, name:"test3"}
  ]

i dont get the type2
  public test = [{type:1, name:'Test3'},
   {type:3, name:"test4"}
  ]

i dont get the type3
  public test = [{type:1, name:'rancho'},
   {type:2, name:"Exps"}
  ]````

Answer (score 0):

Update to this

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
<hr />
<div *ngIf="test?.length > 0">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of test">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.type === 1">
      <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.type === 2">
      <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.type === 3">
      <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
<div>
   <ng-container *ngIf="item?.length === 0">NO data</ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually this is will not work as item is out of scope  you are not using ng-container inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use  [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch). In this example, when `item.type` is not 1, 2 or 3, it will default to display `No DATA`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of test">
  <ng-container *ngSwitch="item.type">
    <p *ngSwitchCase="1">{{item.name}}</p>
    <p *ngSwitchCase="2">{{item.name}}</p>
    <p *ngSwitchCase="3">{{item.name}}</p>
    <p *ngSwitchDefault>No DATA</p>
  </ng-container> 
</ng-container>
```

Comment: i dont get No data i dont know why